# SQLite select statement returns empty array

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to fetch data from SQLite database(NSArray of strings) and populate the contents in table view cells. I tried to execute the query in command prompt and it works fine. But in code, it returns an empty array.

```
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"select img.image from images img,illness i,illness_images ii where img.img_id=ii.img_id and i.i_id=ii.i_id and i.i_id = '%d'",illid];
        const char *sqlStatement = [temp UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            // Loop through the results and add them to the array
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                // Read the data from the result row
                NSString *imgname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];

                [imglist addObject:imgname];
                sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

            }
        }
        else{
            NSAssert1(0,@"Error retrieving image names '%s'",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
```

I tried to debug and when it reaches while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) , it does not enter the loop.
Not sure whats the mistake I am doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `NSLog` after assigning the string query to `temp` variable.
and check if the variable `illid` is giving you the correct value and run that query on the database directly.

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select img.image from images img,illness i,illness_images ii where img.img_id=ii.img_id and i.i_id=ii.i_id and i.i_id = %d",illid];
```

and you better `release` the `alloc`ated object or use class methods setting value, for memory management.

HTH.

Comment: Awesome! You are right. I am not passing the the right value for illid. So dumb I dint realize that so long! Probably I need to catch some sleep. Thanks Himanshu! It really helped.

Comment: BTW, I am doing release below. Din't include the code here :)